# Numeric.LinearProgramming fails with stack build

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I was able to install the related library  hmatrix-glpk-0.19.0.0 using stack but when I run  stack build

I get

```
error:
    Could not load module ‘Numeric.LinearProgramming’
    It is a member of the hidden package ‘hmatrix-glpk-0.19.0.0’.
    Perhaps you need to add ‘hmatrix-glpk’ to the build-depends in your .cabal file.
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
4 | import Numeric.LinearProgramming
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Programs built using Stack can't use any installed package they want. Every package they use needs to be listed as a dependency, either in their cabal file (as your error indicates) or package.yaml. Add `hmatrix-glpk` to whichever of those you have and try again.